# How can I type properly "JSON.parse()" in ts?

Tags: typescript

`JSON.parse(aString)` is typed as `any` by default. However, `any` also includes functions, dates, regexes and other classes which cannot be parsed.

Now I suspect we can be more accurate if we make use of the conditional types introduced in ts 2.8 and inference of the 3.0 but I am a little bit stuck on how to do it. Perhaps there is some existing basic type I am missing, could anyone advise me?

```
const good: BasicType = JSON.parse(aString); // what I need
const bad: any = JSON.parse(aString); // what I do have now
```

[EDIT]
It is now possible to have recursive types and therefore to type JSON objects properly, [typefest](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest#json) being one example of implementation.

Comment: AFAIK the `good` example should be working.

Comment: See [Microsoft/TypeScript#1897](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1897)

Comment: You can assign any to a variable of... any type. So your first example is fine. What exactly is the problem.

Comment: specifically [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1897#issuecomment-338650717)

Comment: @jcalz it seems to be what I am looking for, just add the answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there is no built-in type name in the TypeScript standard library that corresponds to types that can be serialized-to/deserialized-from JSON.  GitHub issue [microsoft/TypeScript#1897](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1897) suggests adding one, although it doesn't look like there has been much movement there.

Luckily it's easy enough for your to create your own type for this, such as [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1897#issuecomment-338650717) suggested in a comment in the aforementioned GitHub issue:

```
type AnyJson =  boolean | number | string | null | JsonArray | JsonMap;
interface JsonMap {  [key: string]: AnyJson; }
interface JsonArray extends Array<AnyJson> {}
```

And then you can use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to overload the `parse()` method to return `AnyJson` instead of `any`:

```
interface JSON {
  parse(
    text: string,
    reviver?: ((this: any, key: string, value: any) => any) | undefined
  ): AnyJson;
}
```

(note that if your code is in a module you will need to use [global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) to get the above to work)

And let's see if it works:

```
const x = JSON.parse('{"id": 123}'); // x is AnyJson
```

Since `x` is known to be `AnyJson` and not `any`, you could now do type guards on it and the compiler should be more aware of its possible structures:

```
if (x !== null && typeof x === "object" && !Array.isArray(x)) {
  // x narrowed to JsonMap
  Object.keys(x).forEach(k => {
    const y = x[k];
    // y is also AnyJson
    console.log("key=" + k + ", value=" + String(y));
  });
  // key=id, value=123
}
```

So that all works.  That being said, the type `AnyJson` isn't a whole lot more specific than `any`, practically speaking.  I suppose you gain the benefit of excluding functions/methods from possible values/elements/properties, which isn't *nothing*... it just might not be useful enough to warrant modifying the TypeScript standard library.  As said in [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1897#issuecomment-72546389), the `AnyJson` type is "within spitting distance of `any`".

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiAUgZwPZygXigI1agGwgEMMAfKOAVwFscIAnKC5YBgSzgHNnKqCCvFOhgMGxEELRwAssTABuALAAoTsEYAzYgGNow2fKgBvVVCgBtANYQQALiisO3ALoP4SacpUBfVeq1dfWlRcUkIAA8NOAATZFgxCQAeDwMAPhM-FX84DQZtPShEAGUAeQA5EzMoMGIGZAgACmrzDSiHJ04uABoWqAYIADd2QcYAfgdGxuAAC3ZkB1IQbqgbe0c2LpXB4gIqCEWEAEosDKWTiipYiE1OCBjqo-cEA28s1R10VigIrCKy8oAOlq9SaAHJjAAidgxSEOACMACYAMw+MFHBRQAD0WJ+UHmsBe0lU-k0UEavwAhJhsNQBFAAGQMqCgSCoMm-GnYSGoHAAKwgOmAkMZzMpoQkgPmEpAFKOJ1MKnMOLxcDqDFQAHd7izUEVpHIwNVSvzBcBAWtkHLAZpUAwAKK6GaNKynKpK8xQT5wb6SbARawubye7G4yQE3ZoQmedB9b1oIiAgioLiNSFrTAigDUqygOch212+0zeagxU23EaIHlwagPgx1RVGZhhb2EEwSORqiyQA)